# How to check if some file is being uploaded at the time of trigger in Azure Data Factory (allow reading files while uploading in ADF)

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, file-copying, azure-data-factory

I have files in the Amazon S3 bucket where I am trying to copy the files to Azure Blob Container using Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory. I have a tumbling window hourly trigger enabled on the data factory pipeline which hits the S3 bucket every hour. ADF pipeline is not copying the files which are getting uploaded on the S3 bucket. Unable to track the files in later triggers also.
[image]

```
Example:
Amazon S3 bucket 
Filename: HealthData.tar.gz
Upload in S3 bucket start time: 2:39 PM
Size: 200 GB
Upload in S3 bucket end time: 3:45 PM (Appox)

ADF Trigger Time(hourly) : 2:30 PM (but not tracked anything)
```

[image]

```
ADF Trigger Time(hourly) : 3:30 PM (but not tracked anything)
```

[image]
Here the problem is ADF unable to track the HealthData.tar.gz file because it is still uploading in the S3 bucket and is not getting copied to Azure Blob Storage

ADF time is getting conflicting with upload time.
Please help me with the solution in Azure Data Factory(allow reading files while uploading in ADF). Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can provide more info for what you are wanting that would be helpful. It sounds like you are trying to copy a file from Amazon S3 to Azure Blob Storage, but when ADF attempts to copy, the file is actually still being loaded in Amazon S3. Does this produce an error in ADF? I would imagine it would. If you give us details on this it could be helpful. Otherwise I will tell you what I would do.

Comment: @TrentTamura Pipeline is not failing but it is not even tracking the files because the file is still uploading in the S3 bucket while the ADF trigger is invoking. Could you please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example, I would think the file would not be copied over at 2pm, but at 3pm ADF should be able to copy the data from Amazon S3 to Azure Blob Store.

You could accomplish this by using a Get Metadata activity in ADF to view what files are new as of last hour, day, week etc. Using this list (and hopefully a log that you maintain that has the files you have already loaded) you can determine what new files exist that you have not loaded to Azure Blob. The pipeline would look something like this:
[image: Pipeline TopLevel]
[image: For Each Activity Detail]
[image: If Activity True Detail]
These screenshots should give you a starting point. Let me know if you struggle with the code detail. You will need to select Child Item level on the Get Metadata from S3. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for waiting. I have uploaded the screenshots could you please take a look at it. In my requirement, I am not using any file log which logs the files. Could you please help me. Thanks

Comment: If you are not using a File Log, then you should use @UtkarshPal-MT suggestion which can listen to an S3 storage system and fire for any new file uploaded. This could then trigger your ADF pipeline